# Customize tooltips in asp.net calendar

Tags: asp.net, calendar, tooltip, render

How is it possible to customize "Go to the previous month" and "Go to the next month" tooltips is standard asp.net Calendar control.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PrevMonthText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.prevmonthtext.aspx) and [NextMonthText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.nextmonthtext.aspx) properties of the [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.aspx) controls accept HTML markup, i.e. they don't encode the string assigned to them.

Therefore, you can use them to render a `<span>` element with its `title` attribute set to the custom text you want to appear in the tooltip:

```
yourCalendar.PrevMonthText = "<span title='Your tooltip'>Your Text</span>";
```